# How to export fbx textures from Blender for use in Monogame

Tags: visual-studio, xna, blender, monogame, fbx

I'm trying to use Blender to make a simple playing card with a texture on either side for the face and back and load it in to Monogame. The model itself is fine and shows on the emulator when run but I can't seem to get the textures included though.

[image: Genymotion emulator]

The textures on the card seem to render ok in Blender. The materials are set to 'shadeless' so they shouldn't be affected by light levels correct?

[image: Card in Blender]

I've tried using the different version settings and various different path modes from 'copy' to 'strip path' when exporting the file.

[image: Export FBX settings]

The content manager has the output directory set to the main content folder so there shouldn't be a referencing problem with the textures I hope.

[image: Content manager]

All the textures themselves are in the same folder.

[image: Textures]

The content is all loaded manually in to Visual Studio.

[image: Solution Explorer]

Here's the code I'm using to draw the card showing the different light settings I've played around with.

```
    private void DrawCard(Model m, Vector3 v, CardFacing c, PlayerFacing p)
    {
        foreach (var mesh in m.Meshes)
        {
            foreach (var effect1 in mesh.Effects)
            {
                var effect = (BasicEffect)effect1;

                effect.TextureEnabled = true;
                effect.EnableDefaultLighting();
                //effect.PreferPerPixelLighting = true;

                //effect.AmbientLightColor = Color.White.ToVector3();
                effect.DiffuseColor = Color.White.ToVector3();
                //effect.EmissiveColor = Color.White.ToVector3() * 2f;

                //effect.DirectionalLight0.Direction = Vector3.Normalize(new Vector3(0, 0, 1));

                effect.Alpha = 1;
                effect.VertexColorEnabled = false;

                Matrix mCardFacing = new Matrix();

                switch(c)
                {
                    case CardFacing.Down:
                        mCardFacing = Matrix.CreateRotationY((float)(Math.PI / 180) * 180) * Matrix.CreateRotationX((float)(Math.PI / 180) * 90) * Matrix.CreateTranslation(new Vector3(0, 0, 0));
                        break;
                    case CardFacing.Up:
                        mCardFacing = Matrix.CreateRotationZ((float)(Math.PI / 180) * 180) * Matrix.CreateRotationX((float)(Math.PI / 180) * 90) * Matrix.CreateTranslation(new Vector3(0, 0, 0));
                        break;
                    case CardFacing.Hand:
                        mCardFacing = Matrix.CreateRotationX((float)(Math.PI / 180) * -20);
                        break;
                }

                Matrix mPlayerFacing = new Matrix();

                switch (p)
                {
                    case PlayerFacing.North:
                        mPlayerFacing = Matrix.CreateRotationZ((float)(Math.PI / 180) * 0);
                        break;
                    case PlayerFacing.East:
                        mPlayerFacing = Matrix.CreateRotationZ((float)(Math.PI / 180) * 90);
                        break;
                    case PlayerFacing.South:
                        mPlayerFacing = Matrix.CreateRotationZ((float)(Math.PI / 180) * 180);
                        break;
                    case PlayerFacing.West:
                        mPlayerFacing = Matrix.CreateRotationZ((float)(Math.PI / 180) * 270);
                        break;
                }

                effect.World = mCardFacing * Matrix.CreateTranslation(v) * mPlayerFacing;
                effect.View = view;
                effect.Projection = projection;
            }

            mesh.Draw();
        }
    }
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: "The materials are set to 'shadeless' so they shouldn't be affected by light levels correct?", the target/effect supports the material as defined by the export: the answer is no.  There is no "Lighting information" provided through the `.fbx` to associate the lights(or lack there of) as an emissive channel.

Answer (score 1):

A 3d model usually doesn't contain the texture itself. An FBX file stores where each vertex is, how they are connected and which part of the texture is at any single point.

It does not store the texture itself. Therefore, you need to load the texture separately the way you load any other texture (you need a Texture2D, even though this is a 3d model).

Then, you can assign your texture to the effect:

```
effect.Texture = cardTexture;
```

I believe that this should render the effect correctly.

This means that you can also easily swap out the texture of your model on the fly, without having to change the model itself. If you model is just a 2d quad, if might also be simpler to just generate it in code, but your current setup isn't wrong either.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I thought the two files created using the pipeline tool were the references to the textures? Files S_J_0.xnb and Z_Back_0.xnb I assumed were created for the textures as the files are called S_J.jpg and Z_Back.jpg

Also, the code I've got worked at one point. I did what was in the image first time round. Then edited the size of the card and lost the textures.

![Cards with textures](https://i.imgur.com/fjnEn75.png)

Comment: It's quite strange that you got it working at some point, but perhaps I'm misremembering something... As far as I know, the FBX format doesn't contain any textures, so Monogame shouldn't be able to access the textures automatically. Have you tried manually setting effect.Texture?

Comment: As I understand it you're right, the fbx is just a text document. The content pipeline tool when it builds the fbx file bundles all the images in to the xnb files and the script references that. This is the original example I started with. The robot model in it doesn't draw the textures of the robot at runtime, they come as part of the model. Manually setting the texture as it draws the vertices is the method I use for the floor and the table. 

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/graphics-games/monogame/3d/part3

Comment: FBX files can contain simple material definitions and references to texture files. Whether or not the blender FBX exporter and the FBX(Model) Content importers support this, I do not know.

Comment: @Strom Hello. I've opened the fbx file and the xnb with Notepad++ and they seem correct. The fbx references the main xnb file (S_J)and then that references the two textures in the other two xnb files (S_J_0 and Z_Back).

https://i.imgur.com/kOJ3d8r.png

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have forgotten to include embedded resources into .FBX. Please, change on your export settings *Path Mode* to *Copy* and enable the button right next to it. Refer to this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kEP34CbPWUo

EDIT:

That didn't work for me, as Monogame content build tool was always failing to build content with error:

```
*/Content/Wall2.fbx: error: The source file '*/Content/*0' does not exist!
```

Then I just exported .FBX without embedded textures but added texture picture manually to Content.mgcb and switched *TextureFormat* to '*NoChange*'
[image]
And that has worked out just fine!

P.S. I would suggest moving this question to https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/